# Use tuple key as variable to select column in Pandas df

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, tuples

I need to iterate over a tuple, then match the column name of a df I am iterating over by row to the key in that tuple. To confuse things further, I am also iterating over my df row by row with itertuples(), but that is not the tuple I am talking about.

for row in df.itertuples():

```
        for key, month in MONTH:
            print(key)
            value = row.key #Does not work
            print(value)
```

How do I get the key from the tuple MONTH and use it to select the column with the name of that key?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, but it is unsatisfactory to my mind - it seems like I should be able to select the column by name with a variable.

```
ikey += 1
            value = row[ikey]
            print(value)
```